# django JSONField regex

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

I'm using Django 2.1 and I have model with JSONField(record):

```
{
    'fields': [
        {'tag': 'x','value': '12345'},
        {'tag': 'y','value': '67890'}
    ]
}
```

To query exact 'value' I use:

```
Data.objects.filter(record__fields__contains=[{'tag':'x', 'value': '12345'}])
```

My question is, how to use regex with 'value'? e.g.

```
Data.objects.filter(record__fields__contains=[{'tag':'x', 'value': '/^123.*/'}])
```

Comment: This will *not* always work, since the order of JSON keys is (conceptually speaking) free, it is possible that the JSON looks like `{"value": '1234', "tag": 'x'}`. As far as I know only PostgreSQL (and MongoDb) have tooling to look into the keys/values in a query.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use PostgreSQL:`from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`

I know it's possible in Mongo with raw query:

    `{ <field>: { $regex: 'pattern', $options: '<options>' } }`

Comment: could we use `Data.objects.filter(record__fields__regex=r(...)`  ?

Answer (score -1):

you can simple:

```
Data.objects.filter(record__icontains='{"tag":"x", "value": "123')
```

see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450635/6392439)

Comment: Can you explain your solution? It will be more useful for the community. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve