# Doing a filter of Python string list against a Django model JsonField

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django JSONField data structure:

```
searchtermlist = {'terms': ['test', 'cache', 'hello', 'as'], 'subscribed': ['product', 'test']}
```

Given a searh string as such:

```
searchterm = 'hello test'
```

What I am doing now to match if JsonField subscribed field has a matching string to searchterm is:

```
for user in CustomUser.objects.all()
    if user.searchtermlist and any(s in (searchterm).lower() for s in user.searchtermlist['subscribed']):
        # Has a match proceed
        pass
```

My fear is that when the number of users gets large, I can't afford to be doing the objects.all() routine. ***Except that shouldn't be a problem?***

My question; is there any more efficient way to achieve the above using tools like Django QuerySet filter?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445176/how-to-write-a-query-to-get-find-value-in-a-json-field-in-django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#containment-and-key-lookups