# Django JSONField query error: operator does not exist: jsonb = bigint

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Let's say I have 2 tables `A` and `B`. Table `B` has a JSON field named `preferences` which contains a field with id of table `A` called `a_id`.

I want to count number of B rows which refers to `A` table rows like this:

```
A.objects.annotate(count=Count(B.objects.filter(preferences__a_id=OuterRef('id'))))
```

However, I get an error that `operator does not exist: jsonb = bigint`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534026/18782190) answer, I should be able to refer to JSON field attributes using two underscores (`__`) between names. Why doesn't it work in my case?

Also, below the error there is a message:

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

But I don't understand to what it actually refers to. I tried casting `OuterRef(id)` to integer through `Cast()` expression but that does not make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **explicitely cast** `preferences.a_id` to an **explicit type**, because it is a `jsonb` on PostgreSQL not an `int`

***solution***

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions.comparison import Cast

A.objects.annotate(count=Count(B.objects.annotate(casted_id=Cast("preferences__a_id", models.IntegerField())).filter(casted_id=OuterRef('id'))))
```

used Django 4.1

Comment: Thanx this worked perfectly with me